# Crawl url, search and save results - no specific address

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, webscarab

The page I am trying to crawl is a directory of chiropractors. I set my search criteria and get search result but the address stays the same. It has no element of search, page number or anything so I am not able to crawl it the usual way.

Is there any way to crawl to a page, set criteria for search and save results?

Thank you.

Comment: is it AJAX page? please share the url

Comment: You can use a library like [selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) to interact with the page and pull the source at any given time

Comment: @ wpercy  Yes, I have been trying to use selenium but it is all new to me so I am adding more questions on SO. Thank you.

Comment: @ Sohan Das - https://www.acatoday.org/Find-a-Doctor

Comment: you have to use selenium.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to give some example search criteria and the results you are trying to extract.

Comment: If you want a tool that can be used graphically and scripted then you can use OWASP ZAP. The ZAP ajax spider uses selenium under the hood but you wont need to code anything.